# Hide Activate/Deactivate actions or add help text to Product2 list view

Tags: standard-objects, list-view, helptext

As part of the standard salesforce functionality around products, there are action links in product list views to "Activate" or "Deactivate" individual products. I would like to disable this functionality, or add custom help text to the list view if disabling this is not possible.

I have looked in the setup menu, but don't see a way to customize permissions on the IsActive field, or add help text for the product object. I don't see any options for something like this on the list view configuration either.

Is this possible to do with standard functionality?